# Не могу отправить POST запрос

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Пытаюсь добавить новую запись в БД, но попытки заканчиваются ошибкой

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

Собственно класс контроллера:

```
@Controller
public class NoteController {
    @Autowired
    private NoteService service;

    @GetMapping("/notes")
    public String notes(Model model) {
        List<Note> listOfNotes = service.findAll();
        Note newNote = new Note();
        model.addAttribute("notes", listOfNotes);
        model.addAttribute("newNote", newNote);
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String createNote(@RequestBody Note note) {
        service.createNote(note);
        return "redirect:/notes";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String deleteNote(@PathVariable String id) {
        Note note = service.getById(Integer.parseInt(id));
        service.deleteNote(note);
        return "redirect:/notes";
    }
}
```

HTML страница c формой добавления:

```html
<body>
 <h1>Заметки</h1>
 <!-- <a href="addPerson">Add Person</a> -->
 <br />
 <br />

 <ul>
  <li th:each="note : ${notes}">
   <div>
    <h2 th:utext="${note.name}">...</h2>
    <p th:utext="${note.text}">...</p>
    <a th:href="@{${note.id}}"> 
     <span>Удалить</span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>

 <form th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${newNote}" method="POST">
  Название: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" size="35" /> <br />
  Текст: <textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="text"></textarea> <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
 </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring не понимает `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` пока ему не поможешь, например, так:

```
@RequestMapping("/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, 
    produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}))
public String createNote(@RequestBody Note note) {
    service.createNote(note);
    return "redirect:/notes";
}
```

Comment: Помогло ещё дополнительно удалил @RequestBody.